# How to log state transitions in Stateless (.NET state machine library)

Tags: c#, stateless-state-machine

I would like to have a log in database of state transitions of my workflow.

Where is the best place to trigger logging with [Stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless)? Should it be set-up for each State configuration :

```
phoneCall.Configure(State.Connected)
    .OnEntry(() => StartCallTimer())
    .OnEntry(() => Log());
```

or there is some way to define it centrally for whole workflow once?

Any other input in this regard is welcome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `OnTransitioned` trigger that will be fired on every transition as central logging facility.

```
_stateMachine.OnTransitioned(OnTransitionedAction);

void OnTransitionedAction(StateMachine<StateEnum, TriggerEnum>.Transition transition) {
    TriggerEnum trigger = transition.Trigger;
    StateEnum source = transition.Source;
    StateEnum dest = transition.Destination;
    // log trigger, source, destination
}
```

Comment: I didn't see this at first because it wasn't a raised-event.